# ROS Answers SE migration: arduino robot

Tags: ros, arduino, robot

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Hello there !I would like to make a robot with arduino but using ros .Do you know any book or tutorials that i am able to read?Because i found some examples but i dont really get some parts!  Also have i to write python or c/c++ is good?
Thank you in advance!

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/202650/arduino-robot/) by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2015-02-07

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The package [ros_arduino_bridge](http://wiki.ros.org/ros_arduino_bridge) is probably what you are looking for if you want to combine Arduino and ROS. See also related blogpost by the author [here](http://www.pirobot.org/blog/0027/).

Also, I suggest picking up [ROS By Example - Volume 1](http://www.lulu.com/shop/r-patrick-goebel/ros-by-example-indigo-volume-1/ebook/product-22015937.html) as a general introduction to ROS. While not focused on Arduino, it is the best ROS introduction I know (and accidentally, is written by the same author as ros_arduino_bridge).

EDIT:
I should also point out that ros_arduino_bridge is basically a ROS driver for Arduino - it allows you to control your Arduino board from within the ROS framework. You will still need an additional, higher-end system to run the actual ROS nodes (Arduino hardware is not sufficiently powerful for that).

---

Originally posted by [Kristof](https://answers.ros.org/users/5409/kristof/) with karma: 141 on 2015-02-08

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ioann_kats](https://answers.ros.org/users/21350/ioann_kats/) on 2015-02-08**:
Thank you very much! :)